# Disable Horizontal Scroll CSS on Mobile Phone

Tags: jquery, css

Question: how do I remove the horizontal scrolling of divs that have a fixed width and is positioned absolutely to the left and right of the entire page?

When I view this on my phone, I can scroll horizontally seeing the excess div contents. I only want the divs to animate in towards the center of the page, then animate out with just a bit showing.

See demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/PRQYJ/1/